# Android Glide загрузка изображения и кэширование

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, glide

Всем привет, у меня возник вопрос, как загружать изображения с помощью Glide   библиотеки, при этом не выводя их на экран , но затем через `N` число времени доставать из кэша, просто

```
Glide.with(this).load(getUrl()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);
```

не работает. Потом он заново  грузит изображение. Кто и как с этим справлялся и стоит ли Glide мучать эти через асинг таски рукописно грузить ??

Comment: По идее либа по умолчанию должна складывать в кэш и в первую очередь искать картинки там. Попробуйте без diskCacheStrategy сделать

Comment: на сколько я помню .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) только и дает сохранение в КЭШ картинки, если его написать и перезапустить сессию без интернета, то этой картинки не будет. тут получается мне больше интересен вопрос как качать изображения библеотекой Glide кэширую их (.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)). но если не написать into(imageView) он не хочет дивгаться(качать) вот в чем прикол

Comment: Не очень вас понял - загрузка не стартует? Попробуйте тогда ещё добавить `into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(100,100) {})`

Comment: спасибо, попробую сейчас

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вообщем, я попробовал добавить в параметр, не помогло. я думаю что было бы правильно , если мгновенно грузить то через  Glide, а если грузить и куда-то складывать  в директорию то мб просто потоком asynctask?? как более корректно будет?

Comment: Вы забыли учесть самую главную проблему, кеш имеет свойство переполняться и то что вы подгружали, может быть удалено до того, как вы его захотите вывести на экран. Glide has a DiskLruCache inside, which is size-bound. So if you fill it up enough it'll start evicting (deleting) items. The default size is a bit south of 250MB. You can restrict it more so it starts evicting sooner. "The problem is that this constrains the user from favoriting many items." https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1737#issuecomment-280159868

Comment: Ещё как вариант можно попробовать такой вариант `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)`: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/420/com/bumptech/glide/load/engine/DiskCacheStrategy.html